# Currency validation issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

one of the validations I want is to make sure that the user does not enter an amount larger than smallmoey limits on SQL (214,748.00 approx). Below is my validation control but it is kicking out entries that are smaller than that amount.  for example, someone entered 1,821.00 and the control restricted it. Can someone see what I am doing wrong?  Thanks.

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator2" runat="server" 
                                        ErrorMessage="Rate cannot exceed 214,748.00" ControlToValidate="txtBudgetDetailRate" 
                                        Operator="LessThanEqual" Type="Double" ValueToCompare="214748.00">
</asp:CompareValidator>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compare Validator checks the **datatype** before comparing the value. 1,821 is not a valid number. So, You might have got the error.

You can use `Type="Currency"` which enforces two decimal fixed precision. Remove that comma and enter value. It should work fine.